# VBA : How to copy column till last non empty cell from active cell which can be dynamic

Tags: vba

I was trying to write a VBA code to find a text and if the text is found it should go 4 rows down and then select the entire column from there. Tried writing the below code but not working

```
Sub FindLevel()

    Dim p_text As String
    Dim myrange As Range
    
    Sheets("View").Activate
    
    p_text1 = Sheets("Output").Range("AA6")
    p_text2 = Sheets("Output").Range("AB6")
    
    
 
    For Each Cell In Range("C5:CI5")
        If Cell.Value = p_text1 Then
           last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
           Cell.Offset(4, 0).Select 'Selected the desired cell
           
           Selection.last_row.Copy
           
           Selection.Copy
           
           Sheets("Output").Activate
           Range("AA7").Select
           ActiveSheet.Paste
           
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to select the entire ROW (not column)

Comment: After this line: Cell.Offset(4, 0).Select - the cursor should go down the row select the entire all non-empty cells (similar to Ctrl shift Arrow down) and then paste in the output sheet.

Comment: Ah ok, so it's not the entire column, it's just the range in that column, from a specific start row to the last row with values.

Comment: yes - Can you please tell me how should I go after Cell.Offset(4, 0).Select

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you mean by p_text1 and p_text2 ..and i am assuming that you have the searching data in "AA6" cell..Then the code will be like this.

```
Sub FindLevel()

Dim p_text As String, sh As Worksheets, lastcol As Long, lastrow As Long
Set sh = Worksheets("View")
p_text = Sheets("Output").Range("AA6")

sh.Activate
lastcol = sh.Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 5 To lastcol
'I am assuming that you want to go column wise..Like C5,D5,E5....CI5 from this below line.
'For Each Cell In Range("C5:CI5")
    If sh.Cells(5, i).Value = p_text Then
        sh.Cells(5, i).Offset(4, 0).Select
        lastrow = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
       Range(Selection, sh.Cells(lastrow, i)).Select
       Selection.Copy
       Sheets("Output").Activate
       Range("AA7").Select
       ActiveSheet.Paste
       Exit For
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```